# sqlite3 python unable to query on a unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

I have a database which holds for example this table.name where name is

> International Circuit "8 Marzo Fotografia" 2° Trofeo Cassero di
>   Montevarchi

I have a widget that looks up the database (table.name) as you enter text into it and as I type in *'fotografia'* the drop down list associated with the widget shrinks to display the text above ('International Circuit "8 Marzo Fotografia" 2° Trofeo Cassero di Montevarchi')

I then take this text from the widget's `wx.textCtrl` (via `GetValue()`) and use the result to query the database to find the rowid of the row containing the text ('International Circuit "8 Marzo Fotografia" 2° Trofeo Cassero di Montevarchi')
I know the row exists (I've seen it on a database browser AND my little widget has come up with the text)

Using

```
sql = """select rowid from table where name = ?"""
```

and

```
cursor.execute(sql, (copied text,))
```

.... I get no results back

I've put various debug points into the app to verify the text is being returned into a variable, I've `.decode('utf-8')`, `.encode('utf-8')` and `unicode(variable)` with no results.

Copying and pasting the offending text into my database browser and running the sql manually - returns nothing. What am I missing/doing wrong here? When I use the rowid for this row - I get the above text back perfectly, I just can't seem to run a query on text that contains unicode characters.

Python version *2.7.5* and sqlite3 version *2.6.0* ...

Comment: Please format your question. The way it is now it's hard to know / get what you actually want...

Comment: Can you be more specific on your table schema and accessing code? Give proper format for us to be able to help you.

Comment: The table schema is basically this :
create tableName as (rowid integer primary key,

Comment: The table schema is basically this :
create tableName as (rowid integer primary key,
name text,
country text) ... basically

my 'widget' takes tablename and columname as parameters and
populates its listbox with a query :
sql = "select " + columnName + " from " + tablename
this sql is then run as a cursor.execute(sql) and as the user
enters data into the control's textCtrl the query is refined with
like clauses.  SMy text above typing in 'fotogra'
the sql in the widget is refined with a like clause :
e.g. 'where column like '%fotogra%' 
This works fine - can't use the results in another query

Comment: Just noticed after a little research that the website that I cut and pasted this text from uses 'charset=macintosh' - not utf-8 and I'm wondering if that could be a problem ?